# Can you be going to cry?

Tags: grammar

I often see people write “I’m going to cry” but does it make any sense? In situations when you feel like you will start crying in the moment, shouldn’t you better use something  like «I’m about to cry» instead?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. "Going to" also has other uses: it can be used to make a prediction based on clear evidence..e.g. "It's going to rain". If this doesn't get closed I will turn that into an answer.

Comment: But in the rain case you also can use “about to”, can’t you? And what’s the difference between these constructions?

Comment: Yes, you could...they are approximately the same. Point is that "going to " is fine, and common usage.

Comment: @Cascabel Okay, thanks a lot! What do I do here to close topic?

Comment: People often use 'going to' when they feel a physical or emotional event approaching, e.g. "I'm going to sneeze".

Answer (score 1):

What words you use is a very personal choice, habit and dialect pays a large part in that choice.

In some languages this may not be a possible answer but in English there are usually dozens of ways of saying the same thing.

To use your example

> I am going to cry

This could mean
**My eyes are welling up I can feel it coming**
or
**I know this event is going to make me cry "Why did I come to see Dumbo I know I am going to cry"**

Some alternative phrases

I am about to cry
I can feel it coming
My eyes are welling up
This is making me cry
Why do I always cry at Dumbo? (just before it become obvious)
I'm on the verge of crying (thanks @Davo)

Comment: Also: *I'm on the verge of crying.*